# How to change Matlab code so the imshow() function shows the correct colors?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imshow

I wrote a simple Matlab code which loads an image and does translation in x- and y-axis. If the image should be translated 10 pixels on the x-axis, I fill the first 10 columns with 0, shift all the columns 10 units to the right and cut the right of the picture by 10 pixels. When I put in positive x-values the loaded picture doesn't show the right colors anymore (with negative values it does) although the RGB values are correct when I print them to the screen!

I already read on the internet, that imshow() does some sort of scaling but that didn't really help me.

So here is the code:

```
clear;
clc;

picture_in = imread('landscape.jpg');    %load picture
[P,Q,RGB]=size(picture_in);              %obtain size of dimension

%Translation
tx=2;
ty=0;

k=0;
j=0;
h=0;
while k<Q
    j=0;
    while j<P
        h=0;
        while h<RGB
            if (round(k+1-tx)>0)&&(round(k+1-tx)<=Q)&&(round(j+1+ty)>0)&&(round(j+1+ty)<=P) 
                picture_out(j+1,k+1,h+1)=picture_in(round(j+1+ty),round(k+1-tx),h+1);
            else
                picture_out(j+1,k+1,h+1)=0;
            end

            h=h+1;
        end
        j=j+1;
    end
    k=k+1;
end
picture_out;
imagesc(picture_out);
```

I would really appreciate some help here. As I already mentioned:
- if the translation is negative, then the colors are correct
- when I look at the tensor of a small image (e.g., 10x10) which gets shifted by 2 pixels then I can see that the first two colums are 0 and the following colums contain the values they should contain.
So I guess it is a problem of imshow()

EDIT (additional comment): the output picture has only the values 0 or 255 for the RGB values but nothing in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works right for me.

One problem you have is that you don't preallocate `picture_out`. It gets created when you first assign a value to it, and is expanded every time you assign another value to it. The first value you assign to it determines its type. If you assign `0` (a `double`), it will become a `double` array. If you assign a value out of `picture_in` (a `uint8`), it will become a `uint8` array. Depending on which direction you shift your image, the one or the other will happen.

A `uint8` image has values 0-255 in it. These are your input values. a `double` image can store values of just about any magnitude, but MATLAB always assumes that such an image has values in the range 0-1. Because you put values in the range 0-255 into a `double` array, MATLAB will, when you call `imagesc`, assume that anything larger than 1 was intended to be 1, and so will show you an all-white image.

So, when you shift your image left, you get a `uint8` output image, and it will display correctly. When you shift your image right, you get a `double` output image, and it will show all white.

The solution is to properly allocate an array before your loops:

```
picture_out = zeros(size(picture_in),'uint8');
```

This will additionally speed up your code.

---

#### Unsolicited advice:

You should learn to use `for` loops, they are much easier than `while` loops. Instead of:

```matlab
k=0;
while k<Q
    % do something
    k=k+1;
end
```

you get

```matlab
for k = 1:Q
    % do something
end
```

Also, instead of looping from `k=0` while `k<Q`, in MATLAB it is more natural to loop from `k=1` while `k<=Q`, as in the `for` loop above.

---

However, you should really not need to loop at all in many cases. Your code can be rewritten much more efficiently as

```matlab
picture_out = zeros(size(picture_in),'uint8');
picture_out(:,1+tx:end,:) = picture_in(:,1:end-tx,:);
```

(for the case that `tx>0`; you can change the indexing to shift the other way.)

---

Alternatively, use [`circshift`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html):

```matlab
picture_out = circshift(picture_in,tx,2);
```

Here, `tx` can be negative also.

Comment: Hey @Cris , although I already found out what the problem was, I thank you very much for the in depth answer which clears everything. Also thanks for the other advice.

Answer (score 0):

So I played around with the code a while and found out that if I don't put the `0` in the `else` clause manually but instead just take it from the picture tensor like this:

```
else
                picture_out(j+1,k+1,h+1)=picture_in(1,1,1);
```

then everything works fine. Digging a bit deeper I found out that I can put in values manually, BUT I need to put them in as an `uint8()` variable.

In the end the code works if I change the `else` clause like this:

```
else
                picture_out(j+1,k+1,h+1)=uint8(0);
```